# Link from private beta user page to network profile broken, presumably because user has no public linked accounts

Tags: bug, status-completed, linked-accounts, network-profile, private-beta

I was browsing some user profiles on the [Politics.SE Private Beta](http://politics.stackexchange.com) (*note: requires private beta access*) and clicking on "network profile". Private betas are not shown on the network profile, which is probably intentional. However, for some users, the link from the private beta user page to the network profile leads to an error 404. I suspect those are accounts that exist *exclusively* on the private beta, and are not linked to any other accounts.

For example, see [this user page](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/18/sven-clement) (*note: requires private beta access*). From this user page, the *network profile* link is broken (error 404). I haven't been able to quickly find another example to test my "lack of linked accounts" hypothesis, because all other users I tested have linked accounts.

Comment: Links are only available for users that are committed to Politics. Maybe post it on Meta.Politics?

Comment: I suspect the issue is true for *any* private beta and that it as a bug is not specific to Meta.Politics per sé. And can't anyone who has the power to fix the bug also access the private beta, being SE staff? But if it's better on Meta.Politics I'm okay with moving it. Should I duplicate the question there and delete it here? I suppose migrating to a private beta is not really a good idea.

Comment: If it is a case for all private beta's then this is the best location.  Only the links are not useful for most users.

Comment: @GamecatisToonKrijthe I added notes that links require private β access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with the next build, we'll only show that link when it should actually go somewhere.

So, it'll be present on all non-private-beta sites; and on for all users who have an account on both a private-beta site and a non-private-beta one.