# Broken "Network profile" link when Area51 is their only account

Tags: bug, area-51, network-profile

When clicking from [this Area51 discussion user page](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/78352/randy-poole) on *network profile*, the result is *Page not found*. Presumably the user has an account only on Area51.

I reported a similar issue [some months ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158571/172266). That issue got [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), but that one was about the case where a users' only account was on a private beta site, and the broken link I'm presently reporting is when a users' only account is on Area51.

Comment: Presumably the same fix is needed. Area 51 just runs on a completely different engine so it probably didn't get that update.