# Why do some Area 51 profiles not have a network profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, area-51, network-profile, 404-not-found

I was  <s>stalking</s> searching some user profiles under new proposals on Area 51. I found some accounts do not have a network profile page. If we click on Network profile in the profile page in Area 51, we are taken to [Page Not Found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlm8M.jpg) with a sign post of a Panda.

If it helps, it is frequently seen in new user accounts aged 1 or 2. Does it happen if the user only has an account on Area 51 and not anywhere on the network or some other reason?

Initially I thought [unregistered user accounts](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/205813/ramanujan-) are only ones with this problem but even some [registered user accounts](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/205811?tab=stats) also take to Page Not Found (Thanks to Rob).

Why is Network profile "Page Not Found"?

Comment: This is going to be one of those "Area 51 is special" things, right?

Comment: Hiding sites: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317967/is-there-a-way-of-hiding-my-network-profile-from-my-profile-on-individual-sites is one possible reason but I don't know that is the actual answer to your question.

Comment: @Mast My question is different. I am asking about redirection to Page not Found when clicked on Network profile.

Comment: Less than an "answer": `Does it happen if ...`, no. --- Some new rep 1 accounts with no other account anywhere (except Area 51) are [OK](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/205836?tab=accounts) and some are [Panda](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/205811?tab=accounts) (click on "Network Profile" on each of those links).

Comment: Duplicate of [Broken “Network profile” link when Area51 is their only account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168770/260388).

Comment: "Area 51 just runs on a completely **different engine** so it probably didn't get that update." – [animuson◆](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168770/broken-network-profile-link-when-area51-is-their-only-account#comment497629_168770)